# Why aren't backticks working in comments to get a fixed-width font?

Tags: support, formatting

I just posted [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/708365/file-name-too-long-for-just-windows-explorer/708371?noredirect=1#comment1694832_708371) (see identical problem in the comment below) that contained the text `\\?\` in backticks (two backslashes, a question mark, then another backslash.)  As you can see here, the text is formatted in a fixed-width font.

In my comment, it is not formatted and the backticks are visible.  Why has this happened?

I edited the comment to make sure I was using backticks and everything is as it usually is.  I have done this before without any issues, is it something to do with the backslashes?

EDIT: From my test comment below, it seems that the final backslash escapes the terminating backtick, causing the first backtick to be ignored.  If I double the final backslash this doesn't fix the problem, so I'm a bit confused about what the correct escaping method would be in this situation.

Comment: This is a test comment with the same `\\?\` text to see if it happens here also.

Comment: Hm... Possible solution: `\\?\ `... Add a trailing <space>? Markdown by default uses backslashes to escape formatting

Comment: This is a test comment with double backticks ``\\?\``.

Comment: @Rahul2001 Doubling the backticks is better ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In my comment, it is not formatted and the backticks are visible.

In a comment you need to double the backticks to prevent the `\` escaping the closing backtick:

```
``\\?\``
```

Comment: Aha, had no idea that was an option!  Thanks.